# Representation for which group and subgroup have same isotypic decomposition

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $ G $ be a completely reducible algebraic group (group for which every finite dimensional algebraic representation is completely reducible). Let $ H $ be an algebraic subgroup of $ G $. Let $ V $ be a finite dimensional representation of $ G $. Since $ G $ is completely reducible there is a canonical direct sum decomposition of $ V $ into isotypic subspaces for $ G $
$$
V= \bigoplus_{\rho_i} V_{\rho_i}
$$
where $ \rho_i $ are finite dimensional irreps of $ G $ and $ V_{\rho_i} $ denotes the sum of all subreps of $ V $ transforming in the irrep $ \rho_i $.

Since $ H $ is an algebraic subgroup of $ G $ then $ G $ completely reducible implies $ H $ completely reducible. Thus there is a canonical direct sum decomposition of $ V $ into isotypic subspaces for $ H $
$$
V= \bigoplus_{\tau_i} V_{\tau_i}
$$
where $ \tau_i $ are finite dimensional irreps of $ G $ and $ V_{\tau_i} $ denotes the sum of all subreps of $ V $ transforming in the irrep $ \tau_i $.

Suppose that the direct sum decompositions of $ V $ exactly coincide for $ G $ and for $ H $. Prove that then every $ H $ subrep of $ V $ must also be a $ G $ subrep of $ V $. In other words, if the isotypic decomposition is the same as an orthogonal sum of subspaces then all the subreps are the same as vector subspaces.

For an interesting example like this where the isotypic decomposition for $ G $ coincides exactly with the isotypic decomposition for $ H $ consider $ G=GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $, $ H \cong SL(2,5) $ the binary icosahedral subgroup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group and $ V= (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 5} $ the $ 5 $th tensor power of the natural representation of $ GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not true: consider the case where $V$ is irreducible for $G$ and $H$ is trivial. Then $H$ is isotypical for $H$, but no non-trivial sub-vector space of $V$ is a $G$-submodule (while it is of course an $H$-submodule).

Comment: Ah! The hypothesis "same isotypic subreps" is not strong enough since as you point out it doesn't even exclude the counterexample with $H$
 trivial. I've asked a new question with the hypothesis "every irreducible $G$
 subrep is an irreducible $H$ subrep and distinct irreps of $G$ correspond to distinct irreps of $H$." This implies equal isotypic decompositions but is stronger. With this improved hypothesis I ask for the same conclusion, that: "every $H$ subrep of $V$ is also a $G$ subrep of $V$." https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4669443/758507 Thanks for helping me improve my question!